# Como impedir que o Highchart conecte os extremos da série?

Tags: highcharts

Estou criando um gráfico utilizando Highcharts que mostra resultados que terminam no mês seguinte, exemplo do **dia 5 de dezembro 2015** a **4 de janeiro de 2016**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, na imagem existe uma linha ligando o dia 5 ao dia 4 do outro mês, essa linha só aparece quando a data termina no mês seguinte, como faço para impedir que essa linha apareça?

Link com o exemplo no jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SV7qy/3/

**Obs:** a data está em milisegundos, no dia 5 de novembro existe um valor de 610, e no dia 4 de janeiro valor 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suas linhas estão ligadas pela ordem que você está passando e não pelo "range" entre uma e outra.

Entao seu array você estava passando alguns pontos que vinha antes desse "primeiro" ai, consequentemente como ele tá mais elevado no eixo Y ele acaba aparecendo, coisa que não aconteceria se fosse no eixo 0 pois ia ficar "invisivel".

atualizei o fiddle pra vc ver, mas o ideal seria ordenar as datas, eu só coloquei de uma forma que não apareça.

http://jsfiddle.net/SV7qy/4/

Comment: Realmente, acreditava que o highchart automaticamente organizava pela ordem de `datetime` e não pela ordem passada, estranho isso. Valeu!